# How do I resolve an "FRM-30408: Invalid value" error in Oracle Forms?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracleforms

My form has a master block (`ORDER`) and a detail block (`ORDER_LINE`). The `ORDER` block has an `ORDER_ID` item (it's primary key) defined as follows:

[image: A screen shot of the ORDER_ID item's property palette]

The `ORDER_LINE` block uses the `ORDER.ORDER_ID` item as an argument to query its records:

[image: A screen shot of the ORDER_LINE block's property palette]

[image: A screen shot of the ORDER_ID argument's property palette]

The `ORDERING_PACKAGE.QUERY_ORDER_LINES` procedure is declared as follows:

```
PROCEDURE
  query_order_lines
  (
    order_lines   IN OUT ORDER_LINE_CURSOR_TYPE,
    order_id      NUMBER,
    line_number   VARCHAR2,
    bin           VARCHAR2,
    plu           VARCHAR2,
    description   VARCHAR2
  );
```

When I attempt to compile my Oracle Form (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>), I receive an error like this:

```
FRM-30408: Invalid value.
Reference: ORDER.ORDER_ID
Block: ORDER_LINE
Procedure: ORDERING_PACKAGE.QUERY_ORDER_LINES
Form: ORDER_FORM
FRM-30085: Unable to adjust form for output.
```

According to the documentation, the recommended solution is:

> Cause:  The value entered for the specified datatype is invalid.
>
> Action: Correct one or more of the following:
>
> 1. The datatype of the argument corresponding to the given value in the procedure argument list of the specified procedure.
> 2. The value of the argument in the procedure argument list of the specified procedure.

Neither of these recommendations work:

1. The data type of the argument in the form (`NUMBER`) is identical to the data type of the procedure's parameter (`NUMBER`).
2. The value of the argument (`ORDER.ORDER_ID`) is also of type `NUMBER` (see first screen shot)

How do I resolve this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah yes, the very helpful help file in Oracle Forms.  "Your parameter is wrong, change it, you donkey."

Not so much help in this case, as the error is a bit more subtle.

The value you are specifying for the argument `ORDER.ORDER_ID` would not be referencable in this case.  You need to pre-pend it with the good ole `:`, to identify it as a bind variable. "`:ORDER.ORDER_ID`" is how it should read in the Value field for the argument.

Essentially, the value column must be an actual value that your form could reference in a PL/SQL block (in the form).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sigh. I wish the documentation gave some examples like that.

Answer (score 0):

The IN Parameter value for ORDER_ID write as :ORDER.ORDER_ID   ---> Need to put a colon (:) ahead of ORDER.ORDER_ID

Comment: This is an answer to a an old thread +12 years that has been already answered with the same solution you have provided, please, when answering check if your solution has already been provided